# Passing props through Link to a child component to complete the url to make an api call

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props

I have a father component (which is a child of HousesGallery and receiving props to display api data), but now I want to display HouseDetail component as a place to show details about the house where you clicked. The api needs the name of the house so I'm trying to pass the name through props via Link and I don't know if I'm missing something in the Route or somewhere else.

App component where the Route is:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
      <div className="got-font">
          <Router>
              <div>
                <Menu/>
              </div>
              <Switch>
                  <Route path="/detallecasa/:name">
                      <HouseDetail/>
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/personajes">
                      <CharactersGallery/>
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/casas">
                      <HousesGallery/>
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/cronologia">
                      <Chronology/>
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/">
                      <HomePage/>
                  </Route>
              </Switch>
          </Router>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Father component:

```
export default function HouseComponent(props) {

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                    {props.info.map((item, i) =>
                    item.logoURL ?
                        <Link to={{pathname: `/detallecasa/${item.name}`, query: {housename: item.name}}}
                              key={i} className="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12 c-houses_div">
                            <figure className="c-houses_div_figure" key={i}>
                                <img className="c-houses_div_figure_img" src={item.logoURL} alt=""/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </Link> : null
                    )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And the child component:

```
export default function HouseDetail(props) {
    const [houseDetail, setHouseDetail] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_URL + "houses/" + props.match.params.housename)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
                setHouseDetail(res.data);
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {houseDetail.map((item, i) =>
                        <div key={i} className="">
                            <figure className="" key={i}>
                                <img className="" src={item.logoURL} alt=""/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: whats a problem?

Comment: The HouseDetail component is no receiving props as I wish. I meant to send it the name of the house to let it make an api call.

Comment: Why are you passing the same data in the route match parameter and route state?

Comment: Cause I clearly have no idea what I'm doing and that's why I'm asking here. So, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Link`'s `to` prop object doesn't take a `query` property, but you can pass additional data in route state

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/detallecasa/${item.name}`,
    state: { housename: item.name }, // <-- Pass route state, if you wanted to
  }}
  ... // other props, etc..
>
  ...
</Link>
```

This issue is more about how you are trying to reference the route's match params in the rendered component.

The access the route match param based on what it is named in the `Route`'s path, i.e. `name`.

```
<Route path="/detallecasa/:name"> // <-- match param is `name`
  <HouseDetail/>
</Route>
```

Access correctly, i.e. `props.match.params.name`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_URL + "houses/" + props.match.params.name)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      setHouseDetail(res.data);
    })
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes so much sense now. But now is throwing: TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Comment: Maybe it's because I have no state in HouseComponent?

Comment: @ZaFra In this case it seems `HouseDetail` isn't receiving [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props), can you try logging the `props` in `HouseDetail` to see what props are being passed. If the route props aren't passed then try either directly rendering `HouseDetail` in the route's `render` or `component` prop (`<Route path="/detallecasa/:name" component={HouseDetail} />`) or use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) react hook (`const { name } = useParams();`)

Comment: It worked using: <Route path="/detallecasa/:name" component={HouseDetail} /> Thanks so much. Now I'll try to understand why :D.

Comment: @ZaFra Basically the same reason why `ComponentB` doesn't receive props from `ComponentA` in `<ComponentA propA={...} propB={...}><ComponentB /></ComponentA>`, it's simply being rendered on the `children` prop of the parent component and won't be passed any additional props.

Comment: @ZaFra Another way to access the route props I neglected to mention is the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC.